# Import Apache Commons Math Library (Beginner)

Tags: java, apache

I want to be able to use the Apache Commons Math Library in Java but I cannot get it to work correctly and the main site is frustratingly unhelpful (at least for a novice like me) and I haven't been able to find a solution on here yet.

I went to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi

downloaded the first option commons-math3-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz

unzipped it and put it into the folder with the java class that I am trying to build.

I then did the command import org.apache.commons.math3;

But I get Error: package org.apache.commons does not exist

Could someone explain (preferably in detail that not even a novice would misunderstand) why this isn't working and what I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: Google classpath in Java.

Comment: You are going to hear about good IDEs like **Eclipse** **NetBeans** and many others that solve your problem, but primarily you are having problem in **integrating 3rd party library code** in your java program. Doing it the **raw way** will require that you set the proper **CLASSPATH** to the path of your library

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am just using Dr. Java

Comment: https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis1xx/resources/java/jar/jarindrjava.html

Comment: I have read that document.  However, there are six jar files.  Which of theses six do I need (or all of them)?

commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
commons-math3-3.6.1-tools.jar
commons-math3-3.6.1-tests.jar
commons-math3-3.6.1-test-sources.jar
commons-math3-3.6.1-sources.jar
commons-math3-3.6.1-javadoc.jar

Once I have the correct one, what do I need to do to actually import the package into the class that I am currently working on?

Comment: Just commons-math3-3.6.1.jar.  And if you follow the instructions on the page I linked to, it will just work.

Comment: I have adding the .jar but what do I need to do actually in java?  Do I have to import something?

I tried just 
org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.BetaDistribution(1.0, 1.0);

but got Error: <identifier> expected

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should just import those classes that you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download jar from repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1

put it to folder `test`, in same folder create file `Test.java` with class `Test` something like this

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Abs;

class Test {

    public static void main (String ... args) {
        Abs abs = new Abs();
        System.out.println(abs.value(-10.0d));
    }

}
```

after that compile it with command `javac -cp "commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" Test.java`

and run it `java -cp ".;commons-math3-3.6.1.jar" Test`

output will be `10.0`

Comment: This would be good advice if OP were running java and javac from the command line.  But he/she claims to be using Dr Java.